# Seemingly good results with training a CNN but bad when testing

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, conv-neural-network

I have trained a cnn model which classifies currency. At the end of training, it seems that the model was performing very good at training and validation data sets. The final accuracies were:

```
Epoch 00020: saving model to model_weights.h5
112/112 [==============================] - 243s 2s/step - loss: 0.3176 - accuracy: 0.8881 - val_loss: 0.3223 - val_accuracy: 0.9014
```

The training accuracy was 88.81% and validation accuracy was 90.14%.
But when testing time came, the model performed terrible. It can't classify even a single correct image. For every image, the prediction was:

```
[0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1.]
```

There was 8 classes. And for every image, only this was predicting. The code I used was the code for testing was the code I copied from Tensorflow specialization at Coursera. The target size is also  correct.

```
for fn in uploaded.keys():
  path = fn
  img = image.load_img(path, target_size=(150, 150))
  x = image.img_to_array(img)
  x = np.expand_dims(x, axis=0)

  images = np.vstack([x])
  print (images.shape)
  classes = model.predict(images, batch_size=10)
  print(fn)
  print(classes.squeeze())
```

The result array should be in order:

```
['10', '100', '20', '200', '2000', '50', '500', 'Background']
```

According to model, it is classifying all images 'Background'.

Here are some of the images I used during testing:
[image: Rs. 10]
[image: Rs. 20]
[image: Rs. 50]
Can anyone help me explain why this is happening. It would be really appreciated.
P.S. These are Indian currency.

Comment: Using dropout always helps. Prevents overfitting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that whatever processing you did for the images used for training you also do for the images used for testing. For example, for the training images did you rescale them with say img=img/255. This is normally what you do for training images. If you did rescale the training images you must do the same rescaling for the test images.

Comment: Oh yes, noob mistake. Inspite I've done it before, I completely forgot about it. And thanks for pointing out!